# How to replace values with the one with highest frequency?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table like the one below.

And another list of IDs. For example say I have list IDs in another table = {"ID1", "ID2"}

I want to lookup each of these IDs in the below and replace the allocation values with the value whose count is the highest.

For example if I filter ID="ID1", the count of "10%" is 3, "35%" is 1 and "45%" is 1. So since 10% has the highest count I need to replace 35% and 45% with 10%.

And then repeat the same for other IDs in the list.

Is there a better way in excel or VBA than doing this manually ?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: If you're changing the values in-place (i.e. overwriting the Allocation column), then this needs to be done programmatically. If you're open to a helper column, formulas should be fine.

Comment: @BigBen In place is not necessary. Going by helper columns, how would I find the value with highest frequency (for only a given ID and not the full column) ?

Comment: What happens if you have a tie?

Comment: @BigBen In case of a tie, it does not matter which value we take. Any one (amongst the two or more tying highest) can be taken and used to replace the others.

Comment: Have you considered to use a pivot table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are OK with the results being in a separate column, as suggested by your comments, then you can use this formula if you have Microsoft 365.

***Edit:** Older `MODE` function replaced with the newer `MODE.SNGL` function.*

Enter into a single cell and the results will `SPILL` down for all of the rows.

- `FILTER` ensures you are only looking at rows with the matching ID
- `MODE.SNGL` returns the most commonly occurring value

```
=BYROW(
    $B$2:$B$11,
    LAMBDA(arr,
        LET(
            f, FILTER($C$2:$C$11, arr = $B$2:$B$11),
            MODE.SNGL(f)
        )
    )
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Sort the sheet by ID first. Results written to column D.

```
Option Explicit

Sub mostfreq()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long, r As Long, n As Long
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
         lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
         r = 2
         n = 1
         Do
             If .Cells(r + 1, "B") <> .Cells(r, "B") Then
                 Set rng = .Cells(r - n + 1, "C").Resize(n)
                 rng.Offset(, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Mode(rng)
                 n = 1
             Else
                 n = n + 1
             End If
             r = r + 1
         Loop While r <= lastrow
    End With
   
    MsgBox lastrow - 1 & " rows processed on " & ws.Name, vbInformation

End Sub
```